# radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^nx^{n!}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

What is the radius of convergence of the following series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^nx^{n!}}{n}$$

Comment: @NormalHuman what is autocomment?

Comment: @darks, those comments are made by his bot, and will be deleted in 5minutes!

Comment: Three questions so far, none with any personal input. Please modify your modus operandi.

Comment: @HamedMaz, please consider adding what you have attempted so far to the question, else it will be closed soon.

Answer (score 3):

$$r^{-1} =\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{2^{n}}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n!}} =1$$